# MySQL update unique value returns Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I have a problem with updating the unique column value in the table.

I have a customer table and I have a separate customer_address table where the customer can have one primary address and others. The primary address is the main address to which the goods are delivered. Customers can have many addresses but one must be primary.

When I try to update I get the message: `Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0-3' for key 'primary_UNIQUE'`

```sql
CREATE TABLE `customer_address` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `address` varchar(525) NOT NULL,
      `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `primary` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
      `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `primary_UNIQUE` (`primary`,`customer_id`),
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

My plan was that all non-primary addresses have a value of 0, and only the primary address has a value of 1.

```
id   |  name        |      address             |     customer_id   |   primary
------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
'2',  'Store 1',     'Address name 24',           '3',                '0'
'3',  'Wholesale',   'Address name 24',           '3',                '1'
'4',  'Store 2',     'Address name 24',           '1',                '0'
'5',  'Wholesale 3', 'Address name 24',           '1',                '1'
```

**How I try to change primary address:**

First, I need to update `id = 3` and set `primary` to `0`. This will cause *Duplicate entry*

```sql
UPDATE customer_address SET primary = 1 WHERE id=2;
UPDATE customer_address SET primary = 0 WHERE id=3;
```

Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: In your table `UNIQUE KEY \`primary_UNIQUE\` (\`primary\`,\`customer_id\`)`, this means that there should be no 2 rows (with primary & customer_id) with the same value. e.g. (row1. customer_id=3, primary=0), (row2. customer_id=3, primary=0) which will cause a conflict.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I don't see any other way to achieve that in a table where there are many addresses and one address need to be  unique for a certain customer.

Comment: Why bother it's just a switch in understanding where 1 is thought of as non primary and 0 is primary? I you must though set id 2 to id before setting id 3 and then set id 2 to 0. Or are you looking for a generic to switch all in the table?

Comment: Use NULL instead of zero for non-primary addresses.

Comment: @Akina Yes you are right. #orginal
`UPDATE t primary = null WHERE id=3;
#new 
UPDATE t SET primary = 1 WHERE id=2;` You can write answer i will accept

Comment: "This will cause Duplicate entry"  No, in MySQl 8 this will cause: "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'primary = 1 WHERE id=2'"    **This is because you should try to avoid using [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) as column names**.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I think your table structure is contradicting the design you posted,

> I have a customer table and I have a separate customer_address table
> where the customer can have one primary address and others. The
> primary address is the main address to which the goods are delivered.
> Customers can have many addresses but one must be

With the above table design you can have only two entries per *customer_id* so you will never be able to store more then 2 addresses per customer, and one will be primary and the other being the non-primary.

For this you might need to redesign your table first to fulfill the requirements you have.

Answer (score 0):

So, a customer's primary address is to become the secondary address and secondary address is to become primary address. The problem is that if you try to modify either of them, then the operation will fail because of the other.

However, we know that `NULL = NULL` is a false criteria, so, you need to set one of them to `NULL`, `update` the other and then `update` the nulled one:

```
UPDATE customer_address SET primary = NULL WHERE id=3;
UPDATE customer_address SET primary = 1 WHERE id=2;
UPDATE customer_address SET primary = 0 WHERE id=3;
```

Comment: In question above @ Akina give me solution. I slove problem seting primary to NULL instead of using 0. But and this your is good example. Thanks for time.

Comment: @Ivan since `NULL` is not equal to itself, basically your `unique` constraint is switched off for the records that have a `NULL` value. As a result, if you leave a value as `NULL`, then subsequently other records can have a `NULL` value as well. So, unless you want to be able to have may records having a `NULL` value, then you will need to switch the value back at the end.